# Unable to start Orientdb as service in windows

Tags: orientdb

I installed OrientDB for the first time on windows following the instructions given here - https://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Windows-Service.html

My JAVA_HOME variable points to this location: C:\Program Files\Java

This is the batch file command to install the service:
installService.bat "%JAVA_HOME%\jre1.8.0_211\bin\server\jvm.dll" C:\dbfiles\orientdb-3.0.18

The service gets created successfully, but cannot be started.
If I directly run the server.bat file, the database starts successfully.

In the system event logs, I see this error:-

The OrientDB Graph Service service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
Incorrect function.